# Discord.js cannot add option to slash commands

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js

I have begun to migrate to discordjs v13 and came across this error: `Property 'options' does not exist on type 'Interaction '`.

runEvent:

```
export interface runEvent {
  interaction: Interaction,
  client: Client,
  args: string[],
}
```

Where it goes wrong

```
export const execute = ({interaction, client, args}:runEvent) => {
    console.log(interaction.options.getString('name'))
}                          ^^^^^^^^
```

What causes this to throw this error? When I log `interaction` itself I can see it has property options. So what throws this error?

As a side note changing `interaction: Interaction` to `interaction: any` fixes this issue instantly. I'm just curious what throws this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because [`Interaction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction) is *any* type of interaction. This includes buttons, select menus and context menus, which don't have the `options` property. You can cast it to [`CommandInteraction`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/CommandInteraction), but it's recommended you use the Typeguards ([`.isCommand()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Interaction?scrollTo=isCommand)) so that if it *is* a different type, it will return instead

```js
export const execute = ({ interaction, client, args }: runEvent) => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
    console.log(interaction.options.getString('name'))
}
```